# Django: I cannot form a table

Tags: python, django, coordinates

I have a model in which there are two fields, one characterized by the element position on the X coordinate of the second Y

```
class Task(models.Model):
    posx = models.IntegerField(blank = True, null = True, verbose_name='X coordinate')
    posy = models.IntegerField(blank = True, null = True, verbose_name='Y coordinate')
```

Visually, it looks like this

```
 |1|2|3|4|5|
1   x 
2 x x   x x
3   x     x
4
5
```

Now the question is, how do I get it properly in html table
where there are empty blocks is not empty.

If you do so

```
Tlist=Task.objects.filter(proj=proj).order_by('posy',)
```

Then the derivation of a pattern I can not understand where is the end of rows in the table.

Comment: What do you have so far, and how doesn't it work?

Comment: Do not post code in a comment.  Post code in your question.  Please (1) Update the question with the code, and (2) delete the impossible-to-read comment.

Comment: Sorry, I did the first time on this site until versed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this to generate the table as a list of lists (two dimensional array), then pass it to your template:

```
def get_table(proj, max_x, max_y):
   table = [[False for x in xrange(max_x)] for y in xrange(max_y)]
   tasks = Task.objects.filter(proj=proj)
   for task in tasks:
      table[task.posy-1][task.posx-1] = True
   return table
```

*(Edit: fixed zero index bug)*

Comment: Thank you, this is the right choice!
PS
table[task.posy-1][task.posx-1] = True